# How do I measure material specific(volumentric) capacitance

Tags: capacitance, supercapacitor, electrostatic

I'd like to test electric capacitance of different powders pressed into solids.
I want to know if my procedure is correct.
First I connect a wire between the material and a ground (ex. radiator) to discharge the material. Then I disconnect the wire and connect red terminal of the multimeter to the material and the other (black) to the ground (radiater).
I repeat the discharging procedure before every measurement. 
Is this the correct and required procedure to follow?

Answer (score 1):

You don't measure the **capacitance** of a material, you measure its **dielectric constant**. No, this won't work.